# ng-html-bind and syntax highlighting

Tags: angularjs

I have an element with `ng-html-bind` that loads HTML content:

```
<p ng-bind-html="content.body"></p>
```

Inside this content I have one or more `<code>` blocks.
I would like to apply syntax highlighting only to the code tags of the loaded content, for example using *angular-highlightjs* directive.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `angular-highlightjs`?

Comment: @JiaJian: yes. If I simply add the `hljs` attribute there are no effects, if I replace `ng-bind-html` with `hljs-source` I get all the content highlighted. The problem is that I have mixed content

Comment: @Mat, is it possible to add the `hljs` attribute to your code blocks in the incoming string?

Comment: Also, note that the [highlight.js usage page](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) says you need `<pre><code>` tags

Comment: @JulianSoro: as I wrote in the question I have code tags inside the HTML content. Adding the hljs attribute... I could try to string replace the code tags of the content and see what happens...

Comment: The string seems correctly set up `text text <code hljs>...</code> text text` but no effects again. I suppose that the directive is not applied (I could disable it to verify this), perhaps a filter could be better in this situation...

Comment: @Mat see my other comment about `<pre><code>` tags. I think this will be essential for using hightlight.js...

Comment: @JulianSoro: yes, I have `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` in the HTML content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97607/discussion-between-julian-soro-and-mat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to bind html on the page with Angular. One way is with `ng-bind-html`, but it's not really the best for this use case, since you also need `angular-highlightjs` directive to compile. You can achieve your goal with $compile like this:

```
/** Here, you will need to do some transformations to your html string
 *  1. Add `hljs` attribute or `class="hljs"` to the `<code>` tag in any `<pre><code>`
 *  2. Hopefully you already have your line breaks in place. This will result in 
 *     a single line code block otherwise. See my plunk for how I added '\n'
 */
var myHTML = $scope.content.body;
element.append( $compile( myHTML )($scope) );
```

[See my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bgZPa51Q7mAqcVNIzGlH?p=preview)

Comment: As you can see in the plunk, whitespace is really important. Every `\n` and space makes a difference in the resulting look.

Comment: Updated plunk a few times, you can click through the versions or play around with it.

Comment: Using $compile should be faster, right? I don't need bindings in this situation

Comment: Technically, since Angular has to instantiate directives within your HTML and create new scopes, ng-bind-html will be faster. But, there lies the problem to begin with...